# Alternatives to center JScrollBar to caret

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I'm trying to automatically center the `JScrollBar` to a caret.  Below is what I'm currently using but since the document text content is too large, it takes about 1.2 seconds to center.

The idea is that when I need to highlight some text, the vertical scroll bar should automatically center the highlighted text to the visible Rectangle, but my current method of doing this is too slow.

This line takes about 1.2 seconds:

```
r = component.modelToView(component.getCaretPosition());
```

Is there another alternative to the above line or different technique to center the vertical scroll bar to caret position? Below is the complete method I'm using.

```
public void centerScrollBar(JTextComponent component){
    Container container = SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JViewport.class, component);

    Rectangle r = null;
    if (container == null)
        return;
    try {   
        r = component.modelToView(component.getCaretPosition()); //Takes about 1.2 seconds
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return;
    }
    JViewport viewport = (JViewport) container;
    int extentHeight = viewport.getExtentSize().height;
    int viewHeight = viewport.getViewSize().height;

    int y = Math.max(0, r.y - (extentHeight / 2));
    y = Math.min(y, viewHeight - extentHeight);

    viewport.setViewPosition(new Point(0, y));
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: you want to center a `JSCrollPane` or the view component of the `JSCrollPane`? Make an image depicting your goal and attach it with your question: that will be really helpful

Comment: you need to divide / 2 both JViewport and JComponent, then whatever is centered to Point

Comment: Sorry I mean center scrollbar to the caret

Comment: If you want that you understand that your JTextPane will have size twice compared to the text content it is possessing. However, you don't want to center the `JScrollBar` you want to center the view rectangle which shows part of the text component, please say that i am correct, or attach an image

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Swing but the idea is that text will be highlighted in the JTextComponent.  Then I need to center the scroll bar so that the highlighted text will be centered relative to the viewable Rectangle.  It is working, but like I said, component.modelToView(...) takes about 1.2 seconds. So looks like you are correct.

Comment: I already tried "component.getVisibleRect()" but the highlighted text is either at the very top or very bottom of the visible Rectangle.

Comment: it's very unusual that the modelToView takes so long - most probably you're doing something wrong, somewhere. No way to help without a SSCCE, as @AndrewThompson already suggested.

Comment: Tip: Add @Sage (or whoever - the `@` is important) to *notify* them of a new comment.

Comment: Looks like the code from [Center Line in a Scroll Pane](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/01/04/center-line-in-scroll-pane/). I've never had a problem using different JDK's on defferent releases of Windows. It scrolls instantly.